# Is this a proper sentence? "Can you send me an email with the contents of what we talked about?"

Tags: email

I did not entirely understand what I talked with someone, so I want to see what he said by text. In this case, can I use the sentence like
"Can you send me an email with the contents of what we talked about?"

I do not know this is the proper, common sentence in my case.

Thanks.

Comment: Your sentence would be understood.  Maybe it is better to say "Would you" (meaning willingness) and not "Can you" (meaning ability).

Comment: It is perfectly natural, though a purist might object that *what we talked about* does not **have** content, it **is** the intended content.  I might say: “Can you send me a summary of this in email?”

Comment: ... and you could say “… explaining what we talked about”, “… providing details of what we talked about”, “… summarizing what we talked about”, etc., depending on what level of information you want.

Answer (score -2):

I would address my need, instead of asking for someone action.
I would say:

> I wish you could provide me some details of what we talked about earlier.

Comment: "I wish you could" usually implies "I know you can't but..."